# Why does the second call to name() print "Alex . n"?

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const char *& name () {
    static const char * n = " Justin " ;
    cout << n << " .\ n " ;
    return n ;
}

int main()
{
    name () = " Alex "; //prints Justin . n
    name(); //prints Alex . n
}
```

So, the first call to name() seems to assign the returned reference variable n to Alex, but then the second call to name() doesn't print out "Justin . n" as is specified inside name().  I don't understand why it doesn't just print "Justin . n" the second time name() is called.

Comment: The variable is initialized on the first call to `name()`. It is *not* reinitialized on later calls to `name()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You took the variable `n`, declared statically inside `name()`, which pointed to a C-string `" Justin "`, then made it point to a C-string `" Alex "`.

So, naturally, when you inspect it later, it still points to a C-string `" Alex "`.

Remember, you declared it *statically*. That means every invocation of `name()` shares the same variable.

If function-static variables were to re-take their initialiser's value every time you entered the function, there would be absolutely no point in making them static!

Comment: But if it's static and const, how is it possible to reassign it to 'Alex'?

Comment: @GianLucaSpadafora It's not `const`. The pointer is fully mutable, so you can change where it points. The thing it points to is considered `const` though (but that's true of both `" Alex "` and `" Justin "` so everything's fine). Remember, `const char*` (or `char const*`) is not `char* const`! :D

Comment: Also, does the second call to name() ignore the line: static const char * n = " Justin " ;

Comment: @GianLucaSpadafora Yes of course. What would be the purpose of it if it retook its original value every time you entered the function? Your book should explain function-statics. Which one are you using?